# Jquery Rondell Multiple Images Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using Jquery [Rondell](http://projects.sebastianhelzle.net/jquery.rondell/examples/carousel.html) plugin for thumbnail carousel as following:

```
<div id="rondellCarousel">
        <a target="_blank" rel="rondell" href="image/US.png" title="...">
            <img src="image/US.png" alt="Band" title="Click to enlarge">
            <h5>Awesome concert</h5>
            <p>My favourite band.</p>
        </a>
    </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#rondellCarousel").rondell({
            preset: "carousel"
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result shows only one image correctly. However, when adding multiple sources as following

```
<div id="rondellCarousel">
        <a target="_blank" rel="rondell" href="image/US.png">
            <img src="image/US.png" alt="Band" title="Click to enlarge">
            <h5>Awesome concert</h5>
            <p>My favourite band.</p>
        </a>

        <a target="_blank" rel="rondell" href="image/US2.png">
            <img src="image/US2.png" alt="Band" title="Click to enlarge">
            <h5>Awesome concert</h5>
            <p>My favourite band.</p>
        </a>
    </div>
```

The second image is not shown in the navigation carousel and instead, when I click on the only image shown in the navigation carousel two images are shown in the appearing lightbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, this is weird. after some trial and error, I found that there is a problem with the Git version. I have downloaded the library again from a different source (their own website) and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

@fareed I'm the developer of the plugin. Could you tell me which version you used initially and which one you use now?
You can find the information at the top of the js file.

Comment: Hi, I will check it in the evening.

Comment: The working verion is 1.1.0. Sorry I can't find the version which was not working as I have deleted it and replaced it.

Comment: Ok 1.1.0 is the latest, so it's fine.